# Sharing files between Ubuntu and Mac - argh, help!

Tags: mac, file-sharing

I have set up an Ubuntu server on an old HP computer. I am trying to use it as a file and print server for two mac books. The print server I have got working (HURRAY!), but the file server is giving me a headache. I am a complete Ubuntu/Linux noob, but have been reading furiously.

I have set up a shared folder (via Samba) called Primary Share Drive (PSD) on an external HDD on the ubuntu machine. The mac can see the shared folder, but when I click the folder it says

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Primary Share Drive” can’t be found.

I have created a different folder on the internal HDD and it works. I can see it and open it. So, the only difference that I can see is that if I go to the permissions tab in the right click menu of the PSD folder, it doesn't allow me to change the group and others folder and files access permissions; it just defaults it back to none. I have set the share tab to share the folder.

Any help/insight would be amazing!

Comment: did you make the folder writable AND browse-able?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through what you are going through (same error trying to open a samba-share folder on a linux server from a mac), and it took me a while to get a handle on what was going on. I am also fairly new to linux, so I hope the other forum members will quickly correct me where I've given bad advice. And please forgive the long-windedness of this response:

I'm guessing Mr. President is right, and that this is a permissions problem. That is, your user doesn't have the permissions to make that folder available to others. So to clarify, the folder that is giving you trouble is on an external hard drive, while the one that works correctly is on your internal hard drive, right? I'm guessing that when your external drive was mounted, your user wasn't given the proper permissions to change anyone else's permissions on that drive, so you can't share it. If you have no idea what I'm talking about with permissions, check this out:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

I'm also assuming based on your question, that you're using a gui and not the command line to do this? The way I resolved this was to use the command line, if you've never used it (though I assume you have), check out a tutorial, there's a bunch online.

You can see who has what permissions on that drive by cd-ing to it, and running ls -l. If we had the drive "myHardDrive", and Ubuntu automatically mounted it, those commands would look like this:

```
cd /media/myHardDrive 
#the above is for Ubuntu 12.04, I think in later versions automount it here
cd /media/<yourUserName>/myHardDrive
ls -l
```

This will show you if you and others have the permissions to read and write to the drive (see above link to understand the output).

I had tried doing chmod to change the permissions, and chown, but they weren't having any effect. The chown command, at least, won't won't work if the drive uses a FAT filesystem since "owning" is not supported. Not sure why chmod wasn't working.

What worked for me was to unmount the drive, and manually mount it, specifying the permissions at the mount command. Check out this page to get started with mounting: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

Unmount the drive, but leave it plugged in.
After having made a mount point (an empty folder) with mkdir, for example:
    `sudo mkdir /media/myHardDrivesNewHome`
Find where your drive is by CAREFULLY running `sudo parted -l`.
"parted" can mess up your computer if you type the command incorrectly, be very careful. That "l" option is the letter "l" as in "list". My printout for one drive looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      24.6kB  315MB   315MB                EFI System Partition  boot
 2      316MB   2190GB  2190GB               AGENT
 3      2190GB  3001GB  810GB                FAT
```

I now know that my drive FAT (in my case, a partition on the same drive as the partitions AGENT and EFI etc.), is located in /dev/sdb3 (and AGENT is at /dev/sdb2, etc.). But it's not mounted so don't try to access the files from here.

Mount the drive to the mount point you made earlier, this time specifying who can do what with "umask". Give the manual for mount `man mount` a good read to understand this command, and know what your filesystem is on the HD to make the commands appropriate to your situation.

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o users,umask=0000 /dev/sdb3 /media/myDrivesNewHome
```

Be aware that umask=0000 gives everyone the ability to do anything to the drive, so maybe someone else here will give us a safer value that will still work for you. I'm just beginning to understand how they work and am leaving it at this for the moment. Also note that my drive has a FAT filesystem (I specified this with `-t vfat`),and if yours isn't those options could be different. Again, all in the man page.

Lastly, you will no longer be able to click on the drive to unmount it after manually mounting it. To unmount, do this `sudo fusermount -u /media/myDrivesNewHome`.

I'm guessing that will make it so you can change permissions and share it on your network. Please, anyone comment if I've given a bad piece of advice here. Take care.

Comment: Dan, thank you so much for the reply! I am still working through your answer. I will let you know how it goes! Thank you again!

Comment: Dan, hallelujah! I got it to work! Thank you, I really appreciate your help on this. I do have a concern that access is very unrestricted (as did you I think). I will continue to research; let me know if you find any further information on this as will I.

Comment: Hmmm...I have added the permissions and it works, but when I restart the machine, Ubuntu reassigns to a new mount point [name]1 with default permissions (the same permissions that caused the issue in the first place).
Any ideas how I can keep the permissions permanent?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu create a folder on your home directory.

```
mkdir ~/MyShare.
```

Right click on folder go to **Properties** and enable sharing for user and guests.

Mount your external drive to MyShare

```
sudo mount -o users,umask=0000 /dev/<your device name> /home/User/MyShare
```

You should now be able to open this on the mac